# how can I use php function link as html href tag

Tags: php, html, plugins, wordpress

I downloaded wordpress plugin bmi-bmr-calculator. The plugin displays menu at the left side and saved history at the bottom.

I want to remove left menu. I check plugin files and found that this method of php is calling BMI link of left menu bar:

```
<li><a id="bmi" href="#" data-formPath="<?php echo plugins_url( 'includes/bmi_form.php' , __FILE__ ); ?>">BMI</a></li>
```

When I'll remove the left menu then I must need this link to call BMI calculator page.

How can I convert this link as an simple HTML

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li>
    <a id="bmi" href="http://yoursite/wp-content/plugins/bmi-bmr-calculator/includes/bmi_form.php">BMI</a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is loading non functional calculator like this http://prntscr.com/983glm

Comment: Not sure. That was the direct link to the file being linked to. Is your menu in a sidebar widget area? If so, you can always use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/ and hardcode your menu into a textarea widget.

Comment: This sound good but can you please refer me any example

Comment: With a plugin like the above, you take your entire sidebar menu code, which includes the aforementioned "<a id="bmi" href="#" data-formPath="<?php echo plugins_url( 'includes/bmi_form.php' , __FILE__ ); ?>">BMI</a>" and add it as a code snippet to the plugin which will then assign that code a [shortcode]. You would take that shortcode and add it to a textarea you would drag into your sidebar widget area.